# short connection distance using BLE on Android 12

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Our application uses Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) for transferring data between Android devices (smartphones) and other devices (controllers). Our application installed on the phone works as a GATT server. Another device (controller) has a role of a GATT client.
To establish the connection between mentioned devices we should make the distance between them about 10 meters.
But it worked for devices with Android OS version until 12. Starting from Android 12 we should make the distance between devices about 1-2 meters.
What's the reason that a device with Android 12 should be closer to another device to connect using BLE?
Is there a way to increase the distance of BLE connection for devices with Android 12?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally, an update of the operating system does not change the Bluetooth coverage of a device. Most likely it is a driver/hardware problem. It would therefore be interesting to know which device hardware was updated to Android 12 in your case.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy A52 Android 12, Samsung Galaxy S20 Android 12, Pixel 6 Android 13, Nokia X20 Android 12

Comment: This sounds weird. Does the advertiser in your use case use the AdvertiseSettings [ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings#ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)? Perhaps the manufacturer has changed the default value there. However, I have neither read nor heard of such a problem ...

Comment: We always use ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH. And it really seems that from 12 Android that value got lower